# Eclipse Can I make a FIXME comment show a little blue bar like a TODO comment does

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse (Juno) when editing Java, by default a comment containing TODO, FIXME, or XXX adds a task linked to the comment. You can change what text in a comment causes this by using Window/Preferences/Java/Compiler/Task Tags.

A comment with TODO in it causes a little blue bar to be shown in the right hand side margin of the editor window, showing where the TODO comment is in relation to the whole of the file. This does not happen for FIXME or other comments. Why doesn't the blue bar show for FIXME comments, and is there anyway to change this whilst retaining the blue bar for TODO comments?

Comment: Which editor? Different editors have different configurations for this

Comment: @greg-449, I don't understand the question. I said In **Eclipse** (**Juno**) when editing **Java**, by... What more information is required?

Comment: Sorry misread question since there was no Java tag. FIXME works for me - look at Preferences > Java > Compiler > Task Tags and check you have FIXME in the list.

Comment: @greg-449 It is there, and it does add a Task, but it does not add the little blue bar on the right hand side of the editor window, which is what the question is trying to ask. I did not add the Java tag, as it's not really a question about Java code.

Comment: Works for me in Eclipse Kepler. What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: First three words of question: In Eclipse (**Juno**)

Comment: Works for me in Juno, too. Try posting a screen shot of an entire editor tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been changing the task tags, and had somehow ended up with FIXME in the General/Editors/Structured Text Edit/Task Tags but not in the Java/Compiler/Task Tags.

Many thanks to greg-449 and E-Riz.